# How to convert sub category values to column in tableau text tables

Tags: tableau-desktop, texttable

I am new to tableau. I have data as below:

| Category1 | Subcategory1 | AmountType | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Sub1 | Actual | 100 |
| ABC | Sub1 | Budget | 200 |
| PQR | Sub2 | Actual | 300 |
| PQR | Sub2 | Budget | 400 |

I want to convert it like:

| Category1 | Subcategory1 | Actual | Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Sub1 | 100 | 200 |
| PQR | Sub2 | 300 | 400 |

Can anyone help me with how this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 calculated fields as below.

Actual =

```
IF [AmountType] = "Actual"
    THEN [Amount]
ELSE
    0
END
```

Budget =

```
IF [AmountType] = "Budget"
    THEN [Amount]
ELSE
    0
END
```

The data would look like

| Category1 | Subcategory1 | AmountType | Amount | Actual | Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Sub1 | Actual | 100 | 100 | 0 |
| ABC | Sub1 | Budget | 200 | 0 | 200 |
| PQR | Sub2 | Actual | 300 | 300 | 0 |
| PQR | Sub2 | Budget | 400 | 0 | 400 |

*Tableau Prep* can also be considered to pivot the data.